# Media query error for landscape iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, css, media-queries

I have a test site up on [cozi.mytakeawaysite.com](http://cozi.mytakeawaysite.com)

I am finding that when in landscape mode the media query does not kick in? I have tried to set to max-width: 480px but this is not working??

The style sheet is style.css

I am reluctant to paste the full code here but any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lets wrap your media query like below:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

If you want some css only for landscape mode try this:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

[More info](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPhone)